# nsoutlineview: right click without invoke "selection did change" delegate method

Tags: menu, nsoutlineview, right-click

as the official "DragNDropOutlineView" sample project,
if i have already selected an item,clicked right button for menu,the right clicked item
will be selected & marked with a blue border,but selectionDidChange method was not invoked.
how did it implement?![enter image description here][1]

Answer (score 0):

answer the question myself,
we can not implement this by coding, instead, we can create a menu in the interface builder, choose the table view or outline view, link the "menu" outlet to the menu you created just now.
now when you right click the item , it won't invoke the selectionDidChange notification.